# Can't navigate to Karma test file from Tests Run tab in IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea, karma-runner

I have an Angular project with Karma/Jasmine tests files. I configured my IntelliJ IDEA (2022.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)) to run Karma tests, which works mostly fine.

One thing that doesn't work is opening the Tests Run tab and navigating to the source for a test by clicking on the test name.

For example on the screenshot below, I expect that clicking on the test marked in red would open the corresponding `project-menu-component.spec.ts` file to the corresponding `it()`, but nothing actually happens when I click:

[image]

I have the following settings:

- [image]
- [image]

Comment: what does the `ngOnDestroy` test definition look like? **Jump to source** doesn't work for specs with dynamically generated names

Comment: @lena You got it in one, we have dynamically generated names exclusively...  If you want to make an answer out of your comment I'll mark it as Solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jump to source** doesn't work for specs with dynamically generated names. Related ticket: [WEB-26625](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26625/Karma-Jump-to-source-from-a-test-doesnt-work-if-the-test-name-is-generated-dynamically), please vote for it to get notified on updates